# Enable/Disable the list of trusted credentials & certificates on iPhone with iOS 9

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, certificate

On Android, you can see and uncheck a certificate via Security/Trusted credentials.

How do you do the same on iOS devices?

Comment: do you want to install the certificate on iOS ?

Comment: @enzo: No, just want to see the installed list.

Comment: Go to settings --> general --> profile and you'll find the list there where you can select each one and uninstall from the delete button